# Scikit-Learn: Adjust train_size or test_size?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, training-data

This is a question regarding best practices for sklearn.

While experimenting with SVMs using the iris dataset provided in the sklearn library. While using train_test_split, I was wondering which parameter to adjust to avoid overfitting. I was taught to adjust test_size (roughly to ~0.3), but there is a train_size parameter. Would it not make sense to adjust the train_size to avoid overfitting, or am I misunderstanding something here?

I get similar results regardless of which parameter I adjust, but I don't know if that's always the case.

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Here is the code I am currently working with:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split as tts
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report

iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data=iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(df)
scaled_df = scaler.transform(df)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=scaled_df, columns=iris.feature_names)

x = df
y = iris.target

#test_size is used here, but is swapped with train_size to experiment
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = tts(x, y, test_size=0.33)

c_param = np.arange(1, 100, 10)
gamma_param = np.arange(0.0001, 1, 0.001)
params = {'C':c_param, 'gamma':gamma_param}

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=SVC(), param_grid=params, verbose=0)
grid_fit = grid.fit(x_train, y_train)
grid_pred = grid.predict(x_test)
print(grid.best_params_)
print('\n')
print("Number of training records: ",  len(x_train))
print("Number of test records: ", len(x_test))
print('\n')
print(classification_report(y_true=y_test, y_pred=grid_pred))
print('\n')
print(confusion_matrix(y_true=y_test, y_pred=grid_pred))
```

Comment: This decision is not really about overfitting or not (although more train-data helps), but about recognizing / evaluating possible overfitting (a trade-off). The more interesting are the SVM params. I also think that ```train_test_split``` should in general work with the assumption: ```train_size + test_size == 1.0```.

Comment: Can it be generalized across all estimators that it's more desirable to have a larger train set than a test set? Thanks.